# Testing a batch job which is scheduled through Handler class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, batch, schedulebatch

In my handler class I schedule a batch class to run and update a field of records after Insert.

I have the below code to schedule the batch to run after insert happens:

```
public class sample{

public static void RunAfterInsert(List<sobject__c> obj){

   batchclassName batchjob = new batchclassName();
   System.scheduleBatch(batchjob,'A Batch Job ',1);


}
```

When I create some records in apex test class which invokes the after insert method to execute the batch. But I guess the batch is not getting scheduled so there is not update happening to the records as per my logic in Batch class.

I think the `System.scheduleBatch(batchjob,'A Batch Job ',1);` is not getting executed through test class. Is it correct? Any way I can make this run? But the batch class is getting covered 100% in through the test class

My test class:

```
@isTest
public class test{

@isTest
static void testmethod(){

    List<Employees__c> employeeList = new List<Employees__c>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<20;i++){ 
        Employees__c emp = new Employees__c(
            Name='Test'+i,
            Person_ID__c=String.valueof(i),
            ID__c = String.valueof(i) + 't',
            Employee_Status__c='Active'
        );
        employeeList.add(emp);
    }
    Insert employeeList;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the test class?

Comment: I believe  , just inserting the records should take care of calling the after Insert method.

Comment: Nope. `scheduleBatch` will schedule, but not run, the batch in question. You have to test both parts of your code separately.

Comment: Okay , Do I have to explicitly execute the batch using Database.executebatch() method here?

Comment: No. Just test your batch separately, in a different class. You won't be able to go end-to-end on this use case. See @AdrianLarson's answer for more details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not going to run the batch. You should **test the batch actions separately**. In this case, you just need to query for the `CronTrigger` and verify that it did, indeed, get scheduled.

```
static testMethod void testAfterInsert()
{
    // setup data

    Test.startTest();
        insert data;
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT count() FROM CronTrigger],
        'A job should be scheduled');
}
static testMethod void testBatchExecution()
{
    // setup data
    insert data;

    Test.startTest();
        Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch());
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert on batch behavior
}
```

Comment: Okay  and do I have to explicitly execute the batch using Database.executebatch() method here?

Comment: You should test `executeBatch` in an entirely separate `testMethod`.